# Pandas - Join Duplicated Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, optimization

I need to combine duplicated lines. 
Some columns I have to sum(*MONEY*), others I have to mantain(*AGE*).

```
DataFrame I Have:
     NAME  AGE   MONEY
0     ANA   20     2.5
1     BOB   17     2.0
2    JOHN   23     1.0
3    JOHN   23     2.0
4  NEYMAR   25  1000.0
5  NEYMAR   25  2000.0
6  NEYMAR   NaN  3000.0

DataFrame I Need:
     NAME  AGE   MONEY
0     ANA   20     2.5
1     BOB   17     2.0
2    JOHN   23     3.0
3  NEYMAR   25  6000.0
```

I have more than 20k lines and speed is important. 
I am using **duplicated** function plus **for index, row in df.iterrows()**. 
It is taking a long time.

Could you help me find a fast method using pandas or numpy...?

Thanks!

Code for testing:

```
import pandas as pd

people = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['ANA', 'BOB', 'JOHN', 'JOHN', 'NEYMAR', 'NEYMAR', 'NEYMAR'] ,
    'AGE': [20, 17, 23, 23, 25, 25, 25],
    'MONEY': [2.5, 2.00, 1.0, 2.0, 1000,2000,3000],
    })

print(people)
print()

people_unique = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['ANA', 'BOB', 'JOHN', 'NEYMAR'] ,
    'AGE': [20, 17, 23, 25],
    'MONEY': [2.5, 2.00, 3.0, 6000],
    })

print(people_unique)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas`, you can `groupby` the `NAME` column, and take the first `AGE` and the sum of `MONEY` using `agg`. I also would `sort_values` by the `AGE`, so that any `NaN` would be at the end (this will guarantee that when you call `first`, it will be a non-null value, given that at least one row has a non-null `AGE` for each `NAME`):

```
people.sort_values('AGE').groupby('NAME',as_index=False).agg({'AGE':'first','MONEY':'sum'})

     NAME   AGE   MONEY
0     ANA  20.0     2.5
1     BOB  17.0     2.0
2    JOHN  23.0     3.0
3  NEYMAR  25.0  6000.0
```